# Symfony2 "No route found" when deploying

Tags: php, symfony, permissions, ftp, cpanel

I need to deploy a symfony2 application on shared hosting with cPanel. I have managed to upload it, set umask for the app/cache and app/logs directories (by adding the umask(0000) line in the needed files, as per the documentation) but I have a strange problem:

It appears to stop working randomly whenever I upload new files with ftp. It always spits out "No route found for GET /(whatever-link)" even though the same files work fine on localhost. Clearing out the cache folder does nothing.

Then, here is the strange part - I believe I have noticed after a couple of hours of inactivity it starts working again with no changes to the files.

This is driving me mad, what am I missing?

Comment: When you say you clear the cache folder, how do you proceed?

Comment: this is a stupid but necessary question: do you update, everytime, your routing files?

Comment: I clear the cache by manually deleting everything in the app/cache folder with the cPanel file manager.
And for routing I use annotations, so I don't need to update the routing.yml (even so, I don't always change routes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the problem and will provide the solution here, to help some unlucky visitors from the future:

The hosting provider had an older version of eAccelerator enabled - one that strips comments out of php files when caching them. Needless to say this caused havoc on my entire application.

I solved it by removing all annotations and instead using yaml for everything, including doctrine mappings.

Read more about the issue here: http://wildlyinaccurate.com/eaccelerator-and-doctrine-2/

Comment: get a vps , really you can get cheap ones where you'll be able to install what you really need and only that , gandi provides very cheap vps, there are loads of other cheap ones ,anyway you should be able to disable eAccelerator on the server at least.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will look into VPS for the future, but this time the client already had a hosting provider. I have found, however, that I quite like the separation of concern that YAML configuration files provide as opposed to annotations.